# Get details of which row clicked in a jquery.click() event

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a dynamic table, with variable # of rows. I'm trying to get related information from the backend depending on the specific row that is clicked.

The table's html (this is from a django template - basically adds one  per object in the db that is returned):

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>pk</th>
            <th>ent_1</th>
            <th>ent_2</th>
            <th>ent_3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for o in object_list %}

            <tr>
                <td><a class="test" href="{% url 'myapp:ajaxview' %}">{{ o.pk }}</a></td>
                <td><a class="test" href="{% url 'myapp:ajaxview' %}">{{ o.ent_1 }}</a></td>
                <td><a class="test" href="{% url 'myapp:ajaxview' %}">{{ o.ent_2 }}</a></td>
                <td><a class="test" href="{% url 'myapp:ajaxview' %}">{{ o.ent_3 }}</a></td>
            </tr>

    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>

<div id="details">
   <!-- details info from the back is appended to the DOM here. -->
</div>
```

The jquery code that catches the event & appends html into the div#details:

```
$(function() {
    $('.test').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("table row clicked")  // sanity check
        update_details();
    });

    function update_details() {
        console.log("update details is called")
        $.ajax({
            // must include the app endpoint at the beginning, others it appends to current url, e.. ajaxlist/get_ajax_details/
            url: "/myapp/get_ajax_details/",
            type: "GET",
            data: {},

            // success
            success: function (rendered_template) {
                $('#details').empty();
                $('#details').prepend(rendered_template)
                console.log(rendered_template);
                console.log("success")
            },

            // error
            error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {
                $('#results').html("<div class='alert-box alert radius' data-alert>Oops! We have encountered an error: " + errmsg +
                    " <a href='#' class='close'>&times;</a></div>"); // add the error to the dom
                console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText); // provide a bit more info about the error to the console
            }

        });
    };

});
```

I've stepped it into firebug, however I do not understand how can I get the full detail of which row has been clicked. **Ultimately, I need the content of the first column of that row that was clicked (the "pk" column)** so I can send that to the backed, so that it returns the rendered_template with the relevent information, which I can them append to my div#details.

OTHER DETAILS:

I'm using classes for selectors. I know I could instead generate an integer ID (e.g. number each rows). But that seems wasteful and I'm sure it's not needed for my purpose. This is a quick prototype, ultimately I'll look into jquery selectors so that I only need to add a class to the table itself (and then listen for clicks on any table>tbody>tr>a within tables that needs to be listened to).

thanks

Comment: off topic, but related:  if you're creating an `<a href=...` then doing `preventDefault` on the click, you probably don't want an `<a>` but instead you should use `<button type="button">{{ o.pk }}</button>`.   As implied in Zam's answer, you probably don't want either and just the text would do `<td>{{ o.pk }}</td>` with the click event on the `td`

Comment: The reason I used an inner tag was that I also used CSS with display:block to make the whole cell clickable (and, by extension, the whole row). Not just the text bits. I am not especially a front-end buy, so perhaps the same result could be achieved w/o an inner  <a> or inner <button>?

Comment: Not sure what css you've used, could possible be applied to a `div`, or not needed at all.  `$("#table_id tbody td").click` would also work (with `this` as the `td`) and assuming you don't have nested tables (with nested tables, use `$("#table_id > tbody > tr > td")` but then make sure you have a `tbody` tag (you should anyway (and you do in your provided code))

Comment: Right I get it - I had been working with links & button (w/o jquery events) up to then, so I was thinking I needed to make the element (button, a) expend to the full size of parent to ensure any click would register. But I understand now that by catching it on the td makes that irrelevent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$(".text").click` handler already knows which `<a>` was clicked, it provides that as `this`:

```
 $('.test').click(function (event) {
     var link = this;
```

you can then pass this to your `update_details` function:

```
     update_details(link);   // or update_details(this);
```

```
function update_details(link) {
};
```

you can then use DOM navigation to find the row and then the first column.  It's up to you where you do this (in the click handler or the update_details, or split between the two), I would recommend only passing the information once you have extracted:

```
$('.test').click(function (event) {
    var link = this;
    var row = $(link).closest("tr");
    var cell = row.children("td").first();
    // or var cell = row.find(">td").eq(0);
```

then you can get the text (excluding the html for the `<a>`) as

```
    cell.text();
```

Put together and shortened gives:

```
$('.test').click(function () {
    var pk = $(this).closest("tr").find(">td").text();
    updated_details(pk);
    return false;
}

function update_details(pk) {
};
```

Comment: That's pretty well explained, thank you.  In the meantime I came up with a .parentElement.parentelemtn.... long winding expression. That's much better.

But to use .text() on the <td> element, I need to first remove my inner <a> in that TD, no? Or would .text() realise it needs to get the text within the <a> so it doen't matter?

Comment: If you use `.text()` it will give you just the text parts, without the html.  So `<a>abc</a>` would give just "abc".  Or even `<div><ul><li><a>abc</a></li><ul></div>` still just the "abc" (and also excluding any element attributes)

Answer (score 1):

Modified your code a bit and attached the click event to the 'td' instead of 'a' tag to source the index of it easily.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#dataTable td').click(function (event) {
     var col = $(this).index(),
     firstColVal = $(this).parent().children('td:first-child').text(),
     row = $(this).parent().index();
     
     console.log("Row index: " + row + ", Col index: " + col + ",  Col Value: " + firstColVal);

     //update_details(); <-- pass required value as parameter
  });
});
```

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td { border: 1px solid #000; padding: 10px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>pk</th>
            <th>ent_1</th>
            <th>ent_2</th>
            <th>ent_3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td><a class="test" href="#">PK Row 0</a></td>
          <td><a class="test" href="#">Ent_1</a></td>
          <td><a class="test" href="#">Ent_2</a></td>
          <td><a class="test" href="#">Ent_3</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td><a class="test" href="#">PK Row 1</a></td>
          <td><a class="test" href="#">Ent_1</a></td>
          <td><a class="test" href="#">Ent_2</a></td>
          <td><a class="test" href="#">Ent_3</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td><a class="test" href="#">PK Row 2</a></td>
          <td><a class="test" href="#">Ent_1</a></td>
          <td><a class="test" href="#">Ent_2</a></td>
          <td><a class="test" href="#">Ent_3</a></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks. Accepted freedom's answer but this one is good as well. Upvoted.